# Java class for AES encryption/decryption of files

Tags: java, file, encryption, aes

Is there a Java class for simply encrypting/decrypting files by only providing source and destination files and AES key without bothering about encryption and IO details?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [Jasypt library](http://www.jasypt.org/easy-usage.html).